# Sorting a list of tuples with the second element of tuple being a list

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have a list of tuples

```
[("Alice", [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]), ("Bob", [3, 1, 5, 3, 2, 5]), ("Clare", [2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2]), ("Dennis", [5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4]), ("Eva", [4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3])]
```

I want the output:

```
[("Alice", [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]), ("Clare", [2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2]), ("Bob", [3, 1, 5, 3, 2, 5]),("Dennis", [5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4]), ("Eva", [4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3])]
```

I want this by sorting the tuples based on the sum of the lists within them.

Currently I have:

```
c = sorted(b, key=lambda x: (x[0], sum(x[1])))
 return c
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have any idea what `(x[0], sum(x[1]))` does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the key should be just the sum of the list, not a tuple, which means:

```
c = sorted(b, key=lambda x: sum(x[1]))
```

[Read more about sorting.](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> lst=[("Alice", [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]), ("Bob", [3, 1, 5, 3, 2, 5]), ("Clare", [2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2]), ("Dennis", [5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4]), ("Eva", [4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3])]
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x:sum(x[1]))
[('Alice', [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]), ('Clare', [2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2]), ('Bob', [3, 1, 5, 3, 2, 5]), ('Dennis', [5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4]), ('Eva', [4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3])]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the sorting to be in place (update the list with the sorted results):

```
 x = [("Alice", [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]), ("Bob", [3, 1, 5, 3, 2, 5]), ("Clare", [2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2]), ("Dennis", [5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4]), ("Eva", [4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3])]
 x.sort(key=lambda i: sum(i[1]))
```

If you want a new list with the sorting result you can do it like @Reut Sharabani suggested.